# Pass value through event in tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I have a program made in tkinter, where when I start I have a window with 2 buttons, each button calls me a class that said class has several widgets, one of those widgets is an entry. And I want that when I hit ENTER in the entry, I execute a function. I print this

```
KeyPress event state = Mod2 keysym = Return keycode = 36 char = '\ r' x = 127 y = 21>
```

The function called is:

```
def search_Modules (self, txt_Search = None):
     try: 
         search_value = txt_Search 
         print (search_value) 
     except: 
         mb.showerror ("ERROR", "The module is empty or does not exist. \ NTest to search by KEY or the complete MODULE")
```

The call to that This function was done like this:

```
self.DESVfr1_entModulo.bind (" Return> ", self.buscar_Modulos)
```

But it doesn't work. However, if I do it from a button, if it works:

```
self.DESVfr1_btnBuscar = ttk.Button (self.DESV_frame1, 
                             text = 'Search', 
                             image = self.SearchModulo_icon, 
                             state = 'disabled', 
                             command = lambda: self .buscar_Modulos (self.DESVfr1_entModulo.get ()), 
                             style = 'DESV.TButton')
```

And it prints the text that I enter in the entry, and I can already work with that text, but I don't know why when I hit ENTER it doesn't work for me. And if in the Return> event, I put the same code as the button, I mean this:

```
lambda: self.buscar_Modulos (self.DESVfr1_entModulo.get ())
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/_init_.py", line 1705, in _call_ 
return self.func (args) 
TypeError: lambda> () takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Event bindings pass in `event` into the lambda but button commands don't pass in events.

Comment: and how can I do it, in my case

Comment: `ttk.Button(..., command=lambda: ...)` and then `.bind(..., lambda event: ...)`.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code. It is appearing all on one line, making it nearly impossible to understand.

Comment: ok I understand, and the function does not have precisely the word event, rather it is like this def search_Modules (self, txt_Search = None) what should I do, leave it like this or change it to def search_Modules (self, event)

Comment: @Bryan corrected

Comment: Yes @cool cloud thank